# In python 3, requests.get().content works to download images, but not for this type of url

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib2, urllib

I've been using different versions of a web scraper to download anime images from a number of websites I like using beautifulsoup, urllib, and requests.
when I have the image link i use requests.get(name_of_url).content and write the file to a directory on my computer. It has been working for other sites but not on this new one. With this new site, the program runs fine, but the file is not written correctly, as I am unable to view it with any image viewers. Here is my code without all of the html parsing, just the url to image download section:

```
import requests
import os

img_data = requests.get("https://cs.sankakucomplex.com/data/ba/bc/babc83a0361198bb43a9b367273b3ef7.jpg?e=1510027320&m=euskBFzOAk-YJJjfbP-26A").content
completename = os.path.join('C:\\', 'Users', 'jesse', '.spyder-py3', 'Image_scraper','sankaku', 'testtesttest.jpg')
with open(completename, 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```

I'm fairly certain that the issue is coming from the different url structure this sight has. If you notice after the ".jpg?" there is more url information, which the other sites I was looking through did not previously have. I'm open to using urllib2 or another library, I'm just learning to use python to interface with html over the last 2-3 weeks. Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated~ 
thank you

Comment: Eromanga Sensei fan? Try adding `headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}` as an argument to `get` and it should work. It seems sankaku doesn't permit scraping, so you'll have to mimic the browser.

Comment: Try with selenium web driver

Comment: I had my user agent filled out in my initial requests from the webpage to gather links, but forgot to add it to the image request. thank you COLDSPEED.

Comment: Also, I'm going to look into the selenium web driver~ thank you flamelite